# Is there any way i can get activity history data from the Instagram using API?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm developing a personal project aimed at analyzing my own Instagram interactions, such as likes, comments, follows, and other activities. My goal is to understand my engagement and activity patterns better. I've explored the Instagram API documentation but am still unclear about the possibilities and limitations of accessing such detailed personal activity history.

---

1. Can I retrieve my own activity history (likes, comments, follows, etc.) using the Instagram API for personal use? Which endpoint(s) are relevant for this purpose?
2. What permissions or authentication scopes are necessary to access my own activity data?
3. Considering Instagram's data privacy policies, are there specific restrictions on accessing or storing my own activity data?

- Reviewed the Instagram Graph API and Basic Display API documentation, focusing on features related to media, comments, and insights, but found limited information on personal activity data.
- Searched Stack Overflow and developer forums for similar questions but didn't find anything recent or specifically aimed at personal project contexts.
- Considered manual data collection but looking for a more efficient and automated approach if possible.